# Selenium-IDE error on type command

Tags: selenium-ide

I need to enter a username in form field, but get an error. Here is the html-code:

```
<input class="_kp5f7 _qy55y" aria-describedby=""
    aria-label="User name" aria-required="true" autocapitalize="off"
    autocorrect="off" maxlength="30" name="username"
    placeholder="User name" value="tst666444" type="text">
```

There's no `id`. How to build a command? I use the command `type`.

> Command: type
>
> Target: name=username
>
> Value: tst666444
>
> In log - error:
>
> [error] Element name=username not found
>
> [info] Test case failed

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. Please, spend little more time and describe you question if you want an answer.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: I cancel my question. I found the solution.